# Rest API Call for Iteration Path

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to send a GET request to get the current iteration. I can get this information per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

However, this only provides the iteration, and not the sprints below it.

For Example:

```
Portfolio
..Release 1
....Sprint 1
....Sprint 2
....Sprint 3
Portfolio
..Release 2
....Sprint 4
....Sprint 5
....Sprint 6
Portfolio
..Release 3
....Sprint 7
....Sprint 8
....Sprint 9
```

**Is there an API call to get a list of all of the sprints below an iteration?**

In the web UI, the iterations are shown as paths...

```
Portfolio/Release 1/Sprint 1
Portfolio/Release 1/Sprint 2
```

... etc

From the settings page, I can see that the iterations are defined as:

```
Portfolio/Release 1
Portfolio/Release 2
Portfolio/Release 3
```

**The third layer does not appear here, but definitely exists as a part of the Iteration Path that can be set in each work item.**

I can work with this information as well.

Comment: I got also the sprints. Do the sprints are configured in the iteration settings? (https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_settings/work)

Comment: interesting... our organization actually has three layers. I'll update the original question.

Comment: How can you see the sprints in the work items if they do not appear in the settings? do you know who configure the sprints?

Comment: I would have to ask around. Is it as simple as adding them to settings?

Comment: yes, very simple.

Comment: I checked with the admin. They correct iterations are in there, but just do not display in the backlog hub.